# android firebase crashlytics Cannot invoke method all() on null object

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

i've implemented firebase crashlytics as documented on it's official website. But when i build my project i get an error below:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method all() on null object

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app’

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method all() on null object
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin$_apply_closure1$_closure10.doCall(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:91)

at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor786.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Here are my implementation versions :

build.gradle (project)

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"
    classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1"
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"
}
```

i've placed my **google-services.json** file under "app" folder.

i couldn't figure out why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project all the dependency versions was separated and kept on different file which is called `versions.gradle`.

it turns out that problem occurs from that file.

```
def app_version = [:]
app_version.major = 1
app_version.minor = 0
app_version.patch = 0
app_version.classifier = null  // like "ALPHA" - "BETA"
app_version.is_snapshot = false
ext.app_version = app_version
```

That was an example of the `versions.gradle` file content

**But that map declaration is causing error on gradle side.** We changed the file content like below and problem solved.

```
ext.appInfo = [
    appVersionMajor         : 1,
    appVersionMinor         : 0,
    appVersionPatch         : 0,
    appVersionClassifier    : null,
    appVersionIsSnapshot    : false
]
```